# showing camera inside my custom panel in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

using phone gap I created face detection app in that we have a option to check the face for that we need to start a camera. Once camera has started it taken to the default camera (away from my app) after capture it return to my app instead of that I need something embedded in my app.

Is there any possible?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html) :

> The camera object provides access to the device's default camera application.

so if you only rely on the phonegap this is not going to work , but as a workaround , you have to write your own native code that you can call on each platform so you could build a custom camera application and bind the result to your phonegap implementation .